# How to programmatically calculate the height of the UIImagePickerController toolbars?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to programatically calculate the height of the top and bottom tool bars in the **UIImagePickerController** view.

Basically, I'm referring to the black regions that contain the camera controls at the top and the round shutter button at the bottom.  Is there a way to do this?

[image: Sample image below]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the picture ratio.  Best photo quality is 3:4, so if it's on this setting, apple adjusts the view so it displays the entire photo while maintaining the aspect ratio.  I'm pretty sure you can use that to calculate the height like this:

```
CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
// at current screenwidth, 'previewHeight' is the height necessary to maintain the aspect ratio
CGFloat previewHeight = screenWidth + (screenWidth / 3);
CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGFloat totalBlack = screenHeight - previewHeight;
CGFloat heightOfBlackTopAndBottom = totalBlack / 2;
NSLog(@"Height is: %f", heightOfBlackTopAndBottom);
```

It could probably be more optimized, but I think this is more clear for demonstration of what is happening.  Also be aware of potential differences in landscape mode.

Comment: Cool!  That comes to the 70 pixels that I was estimating for the iPhone 5, but obviously, with the different screen sizes, it differs for the iPad and iPhone 4.  I think this is what I'm looking for... thanks!!

Comment: Glad it worked, Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Thanks!  This has been giving me fits, so I appreciate your help!

Comment: While we're on the subject, is there also a way to programmatically determine the picture ratio?

Comment: @PeterJacobs - I'm not positive, but I believe so.  Here's where I'd start. You could get the `videoQuality` property of UIImagePicker.  There's only 6 options, and you could find all of their aspect ratios and adjust accordingly.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImagePickerControllerQualityType

Comment: Thanks again Logan.  I'll have a look!

Answer (score 2):

I've been facing the same problem, as I had to add an overlay on top of `UIImagePickerController`. And I've solved the issue by iterating subviews of `UIImagePickerController`'s view, until I get the one I needed. Here an example:

```
- (void)updateOverlayPosition:(UIView *)superView {
    for (UIView *subview in superView.subviews) {
        //CMKTopBar is the class of top view
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"CMKTopBar")]) {
            self.defaultRect = CGRectMake(0,
                                          subview.frame.size.height,
                                          sizeOfYourOverlay,
                                          sizeOfYourOverlay);

            self.overLayView.frame = self.defaultRect;
        } else if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"PLCropOverlayBottomBar")]) {
            //after picture is taken, bottom bar vill appear with picture preview
            static const CGFloat diff = 2;

            self.alterRect = CGRectMake(0,
                                        [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - sizeOfYourOverlay - subview.frame.size.height + diff,
                                        sizeOfYourOverlay,
                                        sizeOfYourOverlay);
        } else {
            [self updateOverlayPosition:subview];
        }
    }
}
```

You can also get all view's class name with View Hierarchy tool
http://cloud.obodev.com/3h2m3x351G0Q

Important moment! Before itereting subviews, of `UIImagePickerController`'s view, make sure it was already presented

```
- (void)showPicker {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [self presentViewController:self.pickerController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:^{
        __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf updateOverlayPosition:strongSelf.pickerController.view];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the height of each (top and bottom) bar separately (not sum of the heights):

Swift 3 code:

```
class YourImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController {
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        if let bottomBarView = self.view.findFirstSubview("CAMBottomBar"){
            print("bottom bar height: \(bottomBarView.frame.height)")
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func findFirstSubview(_ className:String) -> UIView? {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        for subview in self.subviewsRecursive() {
            if subview.className() == className {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func subviewsRecursive() -> [UIView] {
        return subviews + subviews.flatMap { $0.subviewsRecursive() }
    }
}

extension NSObject {
    func className() -> String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
}
```

The name of the top bar class is CAMTopBar